# Is it possible to get the SSLSession in Springboot's Rest controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl

I'm using a wrapped SSLEngine in spring boot for SSL communication. My objective is to generate a TLS fingerprint during the handshake process. This data is pushed to the SSLSession and I want to get this data in the corresponding rest controller.

Any help would be appreciated.